# Heterogeneous map

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, existential-type, higher-rank-types

I need a map which can contain arbitrary values as long as their types are of the same typeclass. My first naive approach was something like this:

```
type HMap = forall a . MyClass a => M.Map Int a
```

but it does not seem to work: the following code gives a compile error:

```
testFunction :: (forall a . MyClass a => M.Map Int a) -> Int -> IO ()
testFunction m i = do
    case M.lookup i m of
        Nothing -> return ()
        Just v -> someActionFromMyClass v >> putStrLn "OK"


Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
  (MyClass a0) arising from a use of `m'
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the second argument of `M.lookup', namely `m'
In the expression: (M.lookup i m)
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  case (M.lookup i m) of {
    Nothing -> return ()
    Just v -> someActionFromMyClass v >> putStrLn "OK" }
```

I thought that I need special heterogeneous collection, but strangely I couldn't find anything in Google except [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hetero-map), but this library seems kind of scruffy and old.
What is the way of doing this correctly (hopefully without other libraries, using GHC extensions only)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using a proper existential type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Elem = forall e. C e => Elem e

type HMap = Map Int Elem
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's a shame I haven't got it myself. I guess I have to sleep more than I do now)