# How do I define a collection of values with units?

Tags: haskell

I want to define a collection of data arrays and associate each with units.  For instance, one member of the collection could be `Vector Float` to which I somehow associate the units meters.  Another member could be `Vector Int` to which I associate the units counts.  Another could be `Vector Double` to which I associate the units centimeters.  My use case is that for each member of the collection, I want to:

1. Display the precision of the data (i.e. `Int` vs `Float` vs `Double` vs `Int64`)
2. Display the numeric values according to the precision (i.e. [1.0, 3.0, 4.0] or [1, 3, 4] as appropriate).
3. Display the significance of the values, including units (i.e. Length meters, Count, Length centimeters).

Each data array is read from a file that defines the array of values, the precision, and the units, so none of these are available at compile time.

How can I define the type for such a collection, say, as an `IntMap`?  Can I do so using existing units related libraries or do I need to roll my own?  I am open to using any GHC extensions needed to get the job done (such as GADTs).

I have encountered the following issues in trying to formulate a solution.

- `Vector Float`, `Vector Double`, and `Vector Int` are all different types, so I cannot put them into the same collection without [existential quantification](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types) such as in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740549/heterogeneous-map).  However, if I use existential quantification using the `Num` class as a constraint, I remove the precision information.
- The units in the `dimensional` [package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional-0.13) are at the type level, so arrays with quantity `Length` cannot be in the same collection as arrays with quantity `Time`.  Again, this might be solved with existential quantification, and again, destroying the needed information.  Other units packages I've found treat units on the type level as well.

One possible solution is to take the units and precision information out of the type level and into the data level:

```
data Quantity = Length LengthUnit
              | Time TimeUnit
              | Count
              | Angle AngleUnit
              etc

data TimeUnit = Sec | MSec | Hour | Day
data AngleUnit = Deg | Rad | etc
data LengthUnit = Meter | Centimeter | Mile
etc

data Precision = Int | Float | Double

data DataArray quant prec = forall e . Num e => DataArray Quantity Precision (Vector e)
```

(This simple units system could be improved by adding prefixes, conversion factors, etc, like units packages usually do.  The example above is just for illustrative purposes.)

This presents a number of problems as well.  For one, it's easy to define a `DataArray` that has inconsistent type such as `DataArray Angle Int (Vector Float)`.  It also smells of reinventing the wheel, both in implementing a whole new units system and redundantly defining the precision of the data.

I feel like I am overcomplicating something that should be simple.  What is a type strategy that achieves my usage goals?

Comment: Why would you store quantities of different physical dimension in a homogeneous container? And why would you _ever_ store physical quantities as integers – that doesn't really make sense, seeing as unit conversion can't be done safely. [There's no very convincing reason to use `Float`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Floating_point), either. (If you want to express _measurement uncertainties_, you should do so with an explicit uncertainty-estimate!)

Comment: @leftaroundabout storing quantities of different physical dimension in the same container is a pretty common thing to do, I think.  In my case, I'm reading a HDF5 file that does exactly that: each data set has a value type (Int32, Int64, etc) and units, as well as an array of values.  "Physical" quantities can be integers due to measurement quantization.  While my HDF5 file does this using enumerations and strings, I want to encode the same information in a more Haskelly and file-format-agnostic way.  Thanks for commenting.

Comment: Existential quantification is certainly incorrect here - at least the way you've used it. It seems that instead of having `data Precision = Int | Float | Double` you should just have `data DataArray precision = DataArray Quantity (Vector precision)`. You seem to imply that you want unit information in the type level, but this is not necessary, which you go on to prove by providing a perfectly valid implementation which doesn't use type level units! If you want to prevent invalid usages, use a smart constructor. In general I think your "usage goals" are very unclear.

Comment: @user2407038 I don't believe your suggested solution works because then DataArray Double and DataArray Int cannot be in the same collection as they have different types.  As for usage goals, they are the 1,2,3 bullet points at the top, which I would be happy to clarify better if you could tell me what you find unclear.  Thanks.

Comment: `data Precision = Int Int | Float Float | Double Double` and `data DataArray = DataArray Quantity (Vector Precision)`

Comment: @user2407038 I understand your suggestion now.  I hadn't considered a precision sum type like that, but it seems simple and straightforward.  Thanks again.